# Android: Use spinner in a sub tab

Tags: android, crash, tabs, spinner

I'm trying to put a spinner in a sub-tab in my android app.  Touching the spinner causes a crash.

Searching seems to suggest that for some reason it is not possible to use spinners in sub-tabs, but this seems silly to me.  I've also tried using activity groups as an alternative to sub-tabs, but I get the same crash.

Has anyone resolved this?

Comment: Please provide stacktrace of crash.

Comment: Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception WindowManager$BadTokenException)) 
 AlertDialog(Dialog).show() line: 245 
 AlertDialog$Builder.show() line: 802 
 Spinner.performClick() line: 257 
 View$PerformClick.run() line: 8816 
 ViewRoot(Handler).handleCallback(Message) line: 587 
 ViewRoot(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 92 
 Looper.loop() line: 123

Comment: ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4627 
 Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method] 
 Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521 
 ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 868 
 ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 626 
 NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]

Comment: Sorry, not sure how to get the formatting to be not terrible on this site.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure about this, but try initializing your Spinner in Java code with the context of the parent Activity, like

```
Spinner spinner = new Spinner(isChild() ? getParent() : this);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no change.  Still gets the same error